# mysql error unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql

Hey I'm tring the following sql query :

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feeds (FileLocation,Title,feeddate,nameofuploader,type) 
   VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."      ',now(),". $_SESSION['name'] .",'file')")
```

but its giving me the error:
Unknown column 'Ankit2' in 'field list'
where Ankit2 is the value to be inserted
Any way around this?

Comment: It's often a good idea to create the SQL first, then feed into `mysql_query` - that way it can be echoed if it doesn't work, and errors can be seen more easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to put single quotes around the $_SESSION variable!

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feeds (FileLocation,Title,feeddate,nameofuploader,type) 
   VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."      ',now(),'". $_SESSION['name'] ."','file')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the sql string right? Please try this to check your sql string:

```
$sql_str = "INSERT INTO feeds (FileLocation,Title,feeddate,nameofuploader,type) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."      ',now(),". $_SESSION['name'] .",'file')"；
print $sql_str;
```

to check the sql_st

Comment: If you prefix your PHP code with four spaces, it will indent. For code like this, I'd reformat it as well, for maximum readability.