# MySQL Unknown column in fieldlist error

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error when I execute this statement in PHP:

```
    $sql = mysql_real_escape_string("INSERT INTO `locations`(`id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor_title`) 
    VALUES (1,`http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D210426849026628615459.0004bd6aaf4e431aab7f9%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dembed`, `Se &quot;Mar Menor&quot; p&aring; kartet`)");
```

I figure it has something to do with the quotes, but I've tried different quotes, which has provided me with another error saying I have an error in the SQL syntax (single quote).

The error that is thrown when the above query is executed is:

Unknown column 'http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D210426849026628615459.0004bd6aaf4e431aab7f9%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dembed' in 'field list'

**EDIT:**

Answer was accepted but only for some of it as I did not test the other info provided: I used PDO to query the database instead with prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql error unknown column in field list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063683/mysql-error-unknown-column-in-field-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `mysql_real_escape_string` on the whole query; you must call it on each one variable separately.

Example:

```
// THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ONLY -- NOT A BEST PRACTICE!
$sql = "INSERT INTO `locations`(`id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor_title`) VALUES ".
       "(1, '".mysql_real_escape_string('http://...')."', ".
       "'".mysql_real_escape_string('whatever')."')";
```

You also have to pay attention to the single quotes around the values that `mres` produces; *these are absolutely critical*.

Now of course the above looks extremely ugly, so you can pretty it up a little:

```
// THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ONLY -- NOT A BEST PRACTICE!
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `locations`(`id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor_title`) VALUES ".
               "(1, '%s', '%s')",
               mysql_real_escape_string('http://...'),
               mysql_real_escape_string('whatever'));
```

The above is pretty much the bare minimum that you have to do to sanitize input to the database. But it would be much better if you used prepared statements instead (either with the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extensions).

Comment: Part answer. Went for PDO prepared statements, and that was easier to manage, so thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string("INSERT INTO 
locations(id,anchor_url,anchor_title) VALUES (1,'http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D210426849026628615459.0004bd6aaf4e431aab7f9%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dembed', 'Se &quot;Mar Menor&quot; p&aring; kartet')");
```

Comment: singlequotes does not work with mres like that. Throws a mysql error (on my server anyhow)

Answer (score 0):

Put apostrophes in strings values, you have a ` character

```
INSERT INTO `locations`(`id`,`anchor_url`,`anchor_title`) 
VALUES (1,'http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fmsid%3D210426849026628615459.0004bd6aaf4e431aab7f9%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dembed', 'Se &quot;Mar Menor&quot; p&aring; kartet')
```

Comment: that is a valid quote mark, so to speak. It's What MYSQL provides if you extract some statements. I used them with some queries that was run before the problem I posted about, and it works wonders. Actually, it has to be those, and not singlequotes for the mres to create a string that does not throw an SQL syntax error (this is all  facts provided by only testing on my server)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that was possible uses the `character to mark a string in MySql, I always uses it how delimiter of a field value. One more thing that I know now